# Next.js - <Image /> doesn't use sizes prop for gif images

Tags: next.js

```
<Image
    priority
    fetchPriority="high"
    quality={100}
    fill
    sizes="15vw"
/>
```

The code above works perfectly for images, but animated images skip the `sizes` prop. To see if it works, I check the `Intrinsic Size`.

The intrinsic size for the animated image is 1000x1000 whether I pass `sizes` or not. I want gif images to be resized just like normal images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Inder It seems Next.js automatically disables the optimization for GIF images. The solution is writing a custom loader. The question is, how to optimize GIF images on the fly just like the Image component?